# Implement dialog manager with node-nlp

Tags: node.js, nlp, chatbot

I'm trying to implement some dialog handling (conversation flow, interrupts in flow since conversation aren't necessary lineart - see this article "https://tutorials.botsfloor.com/dialog-management-799c20a39aad" and its section "Context switching") with node-nlp.

What I would like to do is to handle associated contexts for dialogs correctly.

As suggested by [jseijas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2834119/jseijas), I had a look at the `recognizer` entity to implement such an approach.

```
const bot = {
  libraries: {
    BotBuilder: {
      constructor: {
        bestRouteResult(result, dialogStack, name) {
          return name;
        },
      },
    },
  },
  recognizer(value) {
    this.recognizerValue = value;
  },
  _onDisambiguateRoute() {
    this.defaultDisambiguate = true;
  },
  onBeginRouting() {
    return beginRouting;
  },
};

const session = new SessionMock(undefined, null);

const recognizer = new Recognizer();
recognizer.setBot(bot, true);

// Configure (from https://github.com/axa-group/nlp.js/blob/22dcb22f23c790e5e4f452bca6c1f7bb0c670284/test/recognizer/recognizer.test.js#L52)
await fill(recognizer);
await manager.train();

// Execute processing
session.message.text = 'I want to travel';

// Slot filling
let result = await recognizer.recognize(session);
session.message.text = 'Barcelona';
result = await recognizer.recognize(session);
session.message.text = 'France';
result = await recognizer.recognize(session);
session.message.text = 'I have another question'; // <------
// The bot expects "when" (today, tomorrow, ...) here so the answer is:
// You want to travel I have another question from France to Barcelona
result = await recognizer.recognize(session);

console.log('result = ', result.answer);
```

First, it seems that the text to handle must be put in the session under `message.text` and the current conversation id under `message.address.conversation.id`. I use the first to fill slots. But imagine the end-user wants to switch dialog with a sentence like "I have another question".

I think it's related to methods `dialogStack` and `routeToActiveDialog` in the context and methods `_onDisambiguateRoute` and `onBeginRouting` on the bot.

How can I detect this? What does the conversation id stand for? Would it be possible to have a minimal sample?

In addition, to make the conversation robust, I would like to be able to:

- associated the possible values of a question from the bot (for example, "yes" / "no" or a finite list)
- trigger action (instead of an answer) when the user filled all necessary slots for the answer

Is it something possible?

Thanks very much for your help!
Thierry